# Managing data in store for Blazor server application

Tags: store, blazor-server-side

I am working on a webapi project which will be used by a Blazor server application.
When I used to work with React, I used Redux store. Blazor server is component based as well.
I have been looking through google with no luck and was wondering if there is anything like Redux
that can be used in a Blazor server app for managing store data. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is handled by Nick Chapsas in this tutorial :
[Managing Blazor State Using Redux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_c-ErPaYa8&t=803s)

There is also the possiblity to work with singletons and so on. Not an expert on this topic, hope i could point you in the right direction.

Good luck...